# CHtml::resolveName() cannot pass parameter 2 by reference

Tags: php, yii

I got this error message when working with `CHtml::resolveName`: cannot pass parameter 2 by reference.
here is my simple test code:

```
<?php 
class TestController extends CController {
    public function test() {
      var_dump(CHtml::resolveName($myModels, 'someAttribute');
      exit;
    }
}
```

when I route to this action, it always throws an error. However when I changed the code like this

```
<?php 
class TestController extends CController {
    public function valid($model, $attribute) {
        return CHtml::resolveName($model, $attribute);
    }

    public function test() {
        var_dump($this->valid);
        exit;
    }
}
```

It works!
I have read the documentation for the `CHtml::resoveName()` method in Yii framework, and it uses argument reference. But I don't know why it throws an error when using the first code, it's actually the same as the second one.
Could you help me understand this situation?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing one closing bracket for var_dump function.

```
<?php 
class TestController extends CController {
    public function test() {
      var_dump(CHtml::resolveName($myModels, 'someAttribute'));
      exit;
    }
}
?>
```

One more thing, 
You did not use the function `CHtml::resolveName` correctly. It does not passes variable name, passes its reference.
[Check Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#resolveName-detail)

```
<?php 
    class TestController extends CController {
        public function test() {
          $attribute = 'someAttribute';
          var_dump(CHtml::resolveName($myModels, &$attribute));
          exit;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: do not use **&** while calling functions, **&** should be used infront of variables in function declaration.  var_dump(CHtml::resolveName($myModels, $attribute));   is the correct.

Comment: can u tell why so ?. php.net also mentions & in this way.

Comment: `Note: There is no reference sign on a function call - only on function definitions. Function definitions alone are enough to correctly pass the argument by reference. As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning saying that "call-time pass-by-reference" is deprecated when you use & in foo(&$a);. And as of PHP 5.4.0, call-time pass-by-reference was removed, so using it will raise a fatal error.`      copied  from php.net ... http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Answer (score 1):

Just rewrite like this:

```
CHtml::resolveName($myModels, $dummy='someAttribute')
```

This is because the attribute name passed to function call as variable reference. $dummy='someAttribute' creates temporary variable $dummy to pass it.